# Using chrome 54 console with jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

When I update Chrome 54,I found some problems with console
when I use jQuery higher than 1.1.1 like in pic1.

```
$("html")

[html.js.is-AppPromotionBarVisible.cssanimations.csstransforms.csstransitions.flexbox.no-touchevents.no-mobile]
```

When I use jQuery lower than 1.0.0 like in pic2.

```
$("html")
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Chrome itself defines a `$` function in the console to query for elements .  The result in _pic2_ looks like the result of the native `$`  function of the console. As of that I assume that you either didn't load jQuery correctly or that it didn't overwrite the native `$`. To verify this, you should use `jQuery("html")` in the console instead of `$("html")`.

Comment: jQuery("html") is also like pic1 in higher jquery